# Remove UTM parameters form %%profile_center_url%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

My footer in our emails include a link to %%profile_center_url%%. How do I remove the UTM parameters from this link only? See example code in our footers.

To unsubscribe from emails like this one, please click here

Comment: what is the use case you are trying to solve for? are you using the standard pref center?

Comment: We have a custom pref center.. We use automatic UTMs on all links in our emails. It is breaking the link to pull in sfdc information into the pref center. Its adding another ? in the string.

Comment: are you using cloudpagesurl in your pref center HTML?

Comment: in the footer of our emails we use (href="%%profile_center_url%%") then on pref center page the form action is %%=CloudPagesURL(1234)=%% which goes to a Processing Page (cloudpage) that updates the values in Prefcenter DE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [this official method](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317288&type=1&mode=1) of avoiding adding WAC parameters to your URL:

```
%%[ 
var @URL 
Set @URL = AttributeValue('profile_center_url') 
]%% 
%%[ 
var @Link 
Set @Link = Concat('<a href=',@URL,' alias="Unsubscribe">Manage your preferences</a>') 
]%% 

%%=v(@Link)=%%
```

Keep in mind, this will also remove the native link tracking, so clicks on the above URL will not be counted and contribute to the overall click rate.

Comment: That worked great! Since there is an alias="Unsubscribe" wont that track in the email click report?

Comment: This is not an indication of it being tracked or not. You can verify it by looking at the URL in the email, once it is sent. If it contains one long query string, and your SAP domain, e.g. https://click.subdomain.example.com/?qs=8cbc466e20fbaadc63dc721b3250791528bb4f2cea519ccbc1c10f577acd8c0abec16c883fc5e03367b then it is tracked. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

This use case could also be solved by adding ampscript to your preference center code:

`%%=CONCAT(CloudPagesURL(123456), SUBSTRING('?', 1, 0))=%%`

Comment: This also solved for (cloudpage links) in my emails were the WAC was adding and an extra ? to parameter string. Thanks

Comment: You can also use %%=redirectto(cloudpagesurl(1234))=%% @RogerCrnkovic

Answer (score 0):

In the sending process, under the "configure delivery" tab (the step where you can schedule send), on the right you'll find a tracking section. If you do not want UTM code to appear on your links, de-select 'Track Clicks'